# How to setup an Shopify app with old code

Tags: installation, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am new to work with Shopify and can't find any helpful reference.
I have a task to work on Shopify so I have to setup first the app on my local, the old app code is on GitHub and I am stuck on how to setup this already created app on local.
I created new app and able to install in store.
But not able to find UI after running the old Shopify code it doesn't preview anything. Please suggest to work on this setup this app properly.

I want to setup an old Shopify app in local and work on its UI. Code is available on GitHub.